# Vtiger 7.1 Active Directory

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

Previously installed vtiger 6.5 and had active directory authentication working as per [Vtiger 6 CRM AD](http://craftshelter.de/en/vtiger-crm-6-active-directory-authentication/)

Clean Installed Vtiger CRM 7.1 and followed same procedure again for AD, user authenticates ok but it just loops back to the login page again.

Anyone experience this with 7.1?

Have checked config.php and confirm "$AUTHCFG['authType'] = 'AD';" is there.
Have also run the test ldap script and user also authenticates ok.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be doing everything right but I have found your not the only one with this issue, but if you take a copy of your 6.5 version and migrate to 7.1 using vtiger new files

If you are upgrading from 6.5 to 7.1, you will need to run this process twice. First to upgrade vtiger 6.5 to 7.0 and after that repeat the process to upgrade vtiger 7.0 to 7.1

Download the migration path from the SourceForge site. Patch 6.5 to 7  or Patch 7.0 to 7.1
Unzip patch.zip into Vtiger CRM Folder. A file called vtiger7.zip and migrate folder will be unpacked.
Through browser open /migrate path http://yourdomain.info/vtigercrm/migrate

Someone has successfully compete what you are trying to achieve.

https://discussions.vtiger.com/discussion/188023/vtiger-7-1-active-directory